# Ruby on Rails form validation: default field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do I make Rails treat the "http://" value as blank: if the value is "http://", do not validate website field and insert an empty string (not "http://") into database?

In view:

```
<%= f.text_field :website, value: "http://" %>
```

In model:

```
validates :website, format: { with: /^https?:\/\/\S+/i }, allow_blank: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :if or :unless to conditionally validate (untested):

```
validates :website, format: { with: /^https?:\/\/\S+/i }, allow_blank: true, :unless => ['http://', 'https://'].include?(params[:website]) }
```

Use a before_save callback to convert the string to blank:

```
def before_save
  self.website = "" if ['http://', 'https://'].include?(self.website)

  true
end
```

Comment: You'd better replace 'include' with ==

Comment: @apneadiving, can you explain?

Comment: was just wrong: I read the inclusion cause too quick. My bad so +1 :)